# How get Files name (JSON format) from Public Google Drive Folder

Tags: android, json, google-drive-android-api

I have public Google Drive folder with multiples pdf files. I just want to get files from this folder and show in my Android app in List view. So How can it possible.

So, how i get my folder child files ... Please answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
DriveFile googleDriveFile  = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(googleApiClient, driveId);
MetadataResult mdRslt = googleDriveFile .getMetadata(googleApiClient).await();
if (mdRslt != null && mdRslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
  mdRslt.getMetadata().getTitle();
}
```

Comment: get the result store into `Arraylist` then populate in `ListView`

Comment: Where i put Folder Id and APi key ?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend you to have a look at Retrofit which is used often for downloading Json data type from browser.

You may have trouble but look at simple tutorials on the functionality of how it works. Often (in my cases anyway) you will make a new interface class where you will declare a method with your "url" and the data type you are expecting. In the main activity, you will call that specific method. Bit difficult to explain in writing so try it and post your question or problems.

You might be able to adjust the retrofit to your need (in this case google)